# What is a good way to share (actual) desktop over SSH

Tags: ssh, remote, vnc

Can something such as [X2go](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:newtox2go) be configured to share the actual desktop that is being displayed on the PIs HDMI out? Or does it have to start its own session? If so is there a way to do this with VNC strictly over an SSH tunnel?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with `x11vnc`.

The RealVNC included in the latest Raspbian does this by default.

Comment: if i wanted to access it remotely through a firewall would it work if only the SSH port is forwarded?

Comment: Yes, ssh has tcp tunneling.